# Enfold 4.7.6 Wordpress Theme - Slide-Show (full-width) contains a semicolon "

Tags: php, wordpress, slideshow, updates

After updating Wordpress to version 5.4.2–de_DE , the plugins and the Enfold-Theme to version 4.7.6, the 'Slide-Show (full-width)' contains a semicolon at the end of the Media Element and the pagniation-buttons are not fully shown, on the frontpage.

so long, Tönjes Peters aka thoenix

Comment: Please put answers to your own question in a separate answer post and flag it as the answer. Also, it's probably better to notify the authors of the source directly e.g. by way of pull-request on the git repo or otherwise.

Comment: thx for your hints. I have changed it and i will notify the authors of the source.

Comment: Please provide more details of the problem by providing the code and (linked) context!

Answer (score 1):

First i thought about a common WordPress Problem, but not all Websites, wich i administrate, has got this error. Only websites where the Enfold-Theme is used. After checking all settings, my suggestion was that the error must be found in the source-code. After using *grep* in the server-terminal and checking several scripts i think i found the little 'bastard' in *av-helper-slideshow.php*. One pair of semicolons "" is wrong set in line 724.

```
#vi wp-content/themes/enfold/config-templatebuilder/avia-shortcodes/av-helper-slideshow.php
```

in line 724

change

```
$html .= '</' . $tags[1]. ' ">"';
```

to

```
$html .= '</' . $tags[1]. ' >';
```

I hope this will solve the problem.

so long, Tönjes Peters aka thoenix